# Getting mysql syntax error and cant find source

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, function

I have function that updates log table.

```
function wslog($userID, $log, $where) {
    safe_query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."log ( time, userID, log, where ) values( '".time()."', '".$userID."', '".$log."', '".$where."' ) ");
}
```

And I have this php code:

```
wslog($userID, 'server|'.mysql_insert_id().'', 'servers');
```

But I keep getting syntax error:

- Query failed: errorno=1064
- error=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where ) values( '1269208030', '1', 'server|14', 'servers' )' at line 1
- query=INSERT INTO ws_DII_log ( time, userID, log, where ) values( '1269208030', '1', 'server|14', 'servers' )

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that SQL doesn't like your `log` field name as it is a reserved word?

If so, try putting it is backticks

```
log ( `time`, `userID`, `log`, `where` )
```

Comment: I would have said it was the where, rather than the log. But either way backticking it is a good idea

Comment: nvm, I renamed where row, I guess it affected the query somehow.